# Material Design TextInputLayout PasswordToggle Position

Tags: android, material-design

I used material design to draw my password input box as follow with passwordToggleEnabled, however, the password eyeball icon is too close to the right border. I tried to use paddingRight or layout_marginRight, both are just shorten the input box, and the eyeball icon still close to the stroke line. Any suggestion?

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_password"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/com_facebook_likeview_text_color"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintTextStyle"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="20dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="20dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="20dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="20dp"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
            android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/white"
            app:passwordToggleContentDescription="Show Password"
            app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_sign_up_screen_password_eyeball"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/white"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            right

    >

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:maxWidth="20dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/sign_up_screen_cursor"
                android:textColorHint="@color/com_facebook_likeview_text_color"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with it? Looks quite ok to me. Can you describe/draw what is is exactly, you're going for?

Comment: the eye is too close to the border, i would like to move it inward slightly.

Comment: Did you set the `paddingRight` on the `TextInputLayout` or the `EditText`?

Comment: I tried both...

Comment: You should not use normal EditText within TextInputLayout, but TextInputEditText.